# Using ProjectionExpression on List that contain maps

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3

Say that this is the table struct:

```
[{ name:"test", age:99, 
 Info: [
        { location:"A", num:11  },
        { location:"B", num:99  }
     ]
}]
```

What i want to get is something like this:

```
{ name: "test", 
 Info:[
     {location:"A"},
     {location:"B"}
]}
```

would that be possible? I can't seem to make it work unless I specify the index.

```
ProjectionExpression="name, #mp[0].location",
Select='SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',
ExpressionAttributeNames={"#mp": "Info"}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Would you mind improving the answer or perhaps even write one if there is a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation you can either specify the whole object or with index.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html#Expressions.Attributes.NestedAttributes

Working as documented.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the documentation is clear, your answer does not show anything related to being able to access nested map attribute from a list.

Comment: Answer refer to documentation on how to use nested attributes. I’m glad author got solution to fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky if you do not know the length of list. You could try using a max length for the list and use something like (assuming 3 is the max length)

`ProjectionExpression="#mp[0].location,#mp[1].location,#mp[2].location"`